# jQuery css "+=" not working

Tags: jquery, css, operators

I have this `<div>`:

```
<div class="ball" style="top: 1px;"></div>
```

The `top` property is set using jQuery function `.css` like so:

```
$( ".ball" ).css( { top : var_top } );
```

However, when I try to increment it using this syntax, it doesn't work:

```
$( ".ball" ).css( { top : "+=" + var_top } );
```

I even tried it in Firebug's console like this:

```
$( ".ball" ).css( { top : "+=7px" } );
$( ".ball" ).css( { top : "+=7" } );
```

but neither of these work either.

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.6 or better?

Comment: @RobLowe I'm using the latest jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this

```
$( ".ball" ).css({ top : "+=" + var_top + 'px'});
```

**NOTE:** If `.ball` has `position:absolute` then, its parent need to have `position:relative`;

And it seems your code is also **[working](http://jsfiddle.net/nTrM7/1/)**

Comment: It's parent has a relative position of course but, I'm trying to make a classical Pong game in javascript/jQuery and when the balls gets to the top it won't increment it's property. I guess it's a problem in my code but then, why isn't it working at least in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to retrieve the old value, increment it and than reassign it:

```
var topPosition = $( ".ball" ).css('top');
topPosition += increment;
$( ".ball" ).css('top', topPosition);
```

Comment: You don't need to do that.  You can use += and -= with jQuery css.

Comment: Is this a new feature? I have never encountered it before!

Comment: The feature is new in jQuery 1.6